# Java - Exclude superclass fields from reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, field, superclass

I'm using this code to get all fields associated with an Object. The Object in question has three super classes, and other classes extend from this object.

```
for (Field f : this.getClass().getFields()){
    try{
        fieldName = f.getName();
        fieldType = f.getType().toString();
        //Do more stuf
    }
```

I do not want to get the fields associated with the super classes, but I want all fields in the current class and all those that may extend from it.

How do I filter out which fields are the ones I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each `Field` you can use `getDeclaringClass()` to determine the class that declared the field, so if you have a hierarchy like

```
A
|
B
|
C
|\
D E
```

and you want only fields declared in `C`, `D` or `E`, then you can say

```
for (Field f : this.getClass().getFields()){
  if(C.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getDeclaringClass())) {
    // f was declared by C or one of its subclasses
```

If `this` is an instance of `C` you'll get just the public fields of `C`, if `this` is a `D` you'll get the public fields of `C` and `D`, if `this` is an `A` or `B` you'll get no fields at all.

Comment: More complex than the answer below

Answer (score 5):

> I do not want to get the fields associated with the super classes, but I want all fields in the current class and all those that may extend from it.

You can't get "all those that may extend from it" - but if you use [`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) instead of `getFields()` then you'll only get the fields declared in that class.